# How does RMI server responds to multiple RMI client call?

Tags: java, algorithm, network-programming, client-server, rmi

I have built a file-downloader RMI client-server based application. In that, I don't understand the working of different clients. The files are located at the server side and the RMI has the equivalent proxy-server(called stub) at its side. I have used 10 clients and 1 server for this application.

> Question 1- My question is when ***multiple clients simultaneously*** make RMI invocation
>   after lookup from the registry, in what order does client seed/provide
>   them the file? Means the underlying serving algorithm --- `Is it Round Robin Algorithm OR FIFO algorithm OR some other`?

I am not able to figure this out, when I execute my code I just see that the respective files are being simultaneously downloaded as if files are being copied instead of downloading.

> Question 2- How could a single server serve so many clients and in
>   what order such that the files are getting simultaneously downloaded?

Also, my server side method isn't synchronised, there is no need of synchroniastion!

Comment: Why would downloading be different from copying?

Comment: @dotvav- The main question is q1. What serving algorithm is used by the serve so many clients at once? Please answer that.

Comment: As far as I remember a new thread is created for each request, and a new server port is used for the client connection. This can be verified by adding a breakpoint in your server code, run it in the debugger, and initiate several client invocations.

Comment: @dotvav- I don't have much knowledge of RMI, and hence, I am waiting for a more succinct answer. Thanks for helping though, if you could write an answer for the same, please do the same.

Comment: My experience with RMI is limited as well. But SO has a lot of quality content about this http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+[rmi]+threads

Comment: @dotvav-This is much, much helpful. Thanks a lot **dotvav** .

Comment: @dotvav (1) There is nothing in the specification about a new thread per request. (2) No new sever side port is allocated per client. This is a persistent but erroneous urban myth about TCP.

Comment: @EJP thank you for correcting me, I was expecting you would answer this question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question 1- My question is when multiple clients simultaneously make RMI invocation after lookup from the registry, in what order does client seed/provide them the file?

In no order. They all proceed at the same time.

> Means the underlying serving algorithm --- Is it Round Robin Algorithm

No.

> OR FIFO algorithm

No.

> OR some other?

No. There is no ordering.

> I am not able to figure this out, when I execute my code I just see that the respective files are being simultaneously downloaded as if files are being copied instead of downloading.

I don't know what 'copied instead of downloading' means, but 'simultaneously' describes the situation exactly.

> Question 2- How could a single server serve so many clients and in what order such that the files are getting simultaneously downloaded?

By multi-threading, or adroit use of multiplexed I/O, or asynchronous I/O. It isn't specified. Nothing is specified. The one thing you cannot assume is that it is single-threaded and sequentialized in any way.

> Also, my server side method isn't synchronised, there is no need of synchronisation!

Another assumption, and again completely invalid. There is nothing in the RMI Specification that justifies this belief. You cannot assume an RMI remote object is single-threaded.

Comment: There must be some algo which guides the downloading process at the server side! In my question, *File copied meant copying on the same machine, whereas from downloading I meant file-downloading from different machine,i.e, the server*. Please tell me if it's not specified, then how does that work. RMI's internal code might have utilised some technique, which must be constant across all platforms, since it is Java. Please answer & thanks for your detailed answer.

Comment: And, I believe multiplexing IO is almost similar to Round Robin. Means, one at a time, and all getting served after a small token of time switching at the server side, till the files are downloaded.

Comment: @asad You are making several completely baseless assumptions. Just proceed as though the RMI server is multithreaded automatically and you won't go wrong. Your own observations confirm it. There is no 'algorithm' or 'round robin' or 'one at a time' or 'token of time switching' (whatever that means) about it.

Comment: @shekharsuman You don't know what OS he is using, and you therefore can't assert how it does scheduling. Consider a pre-emptive real-time OS. asad's question was about RMI, not operating systems: see the tags. The question can't be answered by reference to any implementation unless there is wording in the specification to mandate that specific behaviour: to the contrary, the wording in the specification is deliberately as vague as it could possibly be: 'no guarantee'. Any assumptions or claims about algorithms are simply invalid, and specifically contradicted by the specification.

Comment: @EJP-Thanks EJP and thanks Shekhar for clarifying all the doubts. What I actually meant was that if multiplexing IO is the same as the one called Round-Robin algorithm used in OS scheduling. Shekhar has understood the analogy. But, this succinct answer has cleared my doubt. Also, the last question was just a point that I stated, not a question which you have answered. Thanks AGAIN ***EJP***...

Comment: @shekharsuman I don't know what to say to all this waffle. Multiplexed I/O has nothing to do with the 'round-robin scheduling used in the OS'. It moves the scheduling *out of* the OS *into* the application, which can process the set of ready socket FDs any way it likes: round-robin, pre-emptively, one per cycle, some never, ... It is impossible to make assertions about this behaviour of RMI: there is nothing in the specification that mandates any specific behaviour. The one thing you cannot assume is that it is single-threaded and sequentialized, because of the lack of any guarantee.

Comment: @shekharsuman That's just more irrelevant waffle. Please stop it. You *are* the one who brought OS scheduling into it, and it *is* irrelevant. It's up there in black and white. You're arguing with history. I have no belief that this answer is 'perfect', but at least it sticks to the point. Try it.

Comment: @EJP-Sorry EJP, it seems my comments have hurt you. Removing those nuisances... I don't want you to be worried because of any such waffle.